# How should questions about coffee flavor be handled?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a post asking about the [flavor of coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-v60-and-aeropress-affect-flavor). As a food site, these questions will certainly end up in the private beta. These questions may be subjective (what is sweet to one is bitter to another), but I don't know if we should just close all questions of this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all flavor questions should be fair game - there is an entire field (sensory science) dedicated to understanding human perception and preferences of flavor. Many of us are interested in coffee!

For example, I answered [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-will-cold-brewed-coffee-differ-from-traditional-hot-water-extration-method/194#194), using a system that robustly measures flavor, and without including biased opinions.

Answer (score 3):

It may depend. If they are asking something like:

- Is It Preferred To Have Flavor A or Flavor B

That will be subjective and primarily opinion-based as every one has their favorite choice. But if the question is something like this:

- Will This Affect The Flavor of The Coffee

That will not be subjective due to the fact it is just asking of the flavor will change or not. This is the situation with the question you posted. The asker just wants to see how the flavor will change, not which one is the best and why. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Also "HOW will this affect the flavor", e.g. make it more bitter, sweeter, etc.